# Is it possible to assign an object while destructuring another (WHILE using defaults in destructuring)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-next

My end goal is to be able to assign a new object using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from an object that is [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) while assigning default values (if they don't exist).

It looks like this may not be possible how I'd like it. Here's my expectations and attempts:

```js
//Expected beginning object
const a1 = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
};

//Expected end result
const b1 = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: "nestedVal1",
  },
};

//Expected beginning object
const a2 = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: "actualValue",
  }
}

//Expected end result
const b2 = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: "actualValue",
  },
};
```

Snippet 1: Does not assign `default` values.

```js
const a = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
}

const {...b} = {
  key1,
  key2,
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: nestedKey1 = "nestedVal1",
  } = {},
  key4 = 'someDefault'
} = a

console.log(b); // does not have key3, or key4
console.log(key4); //this exists as a const, key3 does not
```

Snippet 2: Functional, but can become problematic if multiple levels of nesting are required.

```js
const a = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
}

let {
  key1,
  key2,
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: nestedKey1 = "nestedVal1",
  } = {},
} = a

const key3 = a.key3 || {}; // is it possible to include this in the destructuring? Specifically in the destructuring which defines the default.

const b = {
  key1,
  key2,
  key3: {
    ...key3,
    nestedKey1,
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

Snippet 2 (showing that nested objects aren't overwritten)

```js
const a = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
  key3: {
    someOtherKey: "itWorks",
  }
}

let {
  key1,
  key2,
  key3: {
    nestedKey1: nestedKey1 = "nestedVal1",
  } = {},
} = a

const key3 = a.key3 || {};

const b2 = {
  key1,
  key2,
  key3: {
    ...key3,
    nestedKey1,
  }
}

console.log(b2);
```

Comment: you're close, you just need to remember that order matters when using the spread operator, as later values will override earlier ones. Try something like `{
    ...a,
    key3: {
      nestedKey1: "nestedVal1",
      ...a.key3,
    }
  }`

Comment: @Hamms I've updated my second snippet to fix the error. I believe it functions as expected though. If a value already exists on the object --> don't overwrite it. If it doesn't exist, define it with a default value (including nested object values without overwriting other pre-existing keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion arises from the similarity of destructuring syntax to that of object declaration syntax.

This is object declaration:

```
const a = {
  key1: "test1",
  key2: "test2",
}
```

This is destructuring

```
const { key1, key2 } = a

console.log(key1)  // => test1
console.log(key2)  // => test2
```

Next, you need to remember that assignment operator `=` is right associative in JavaScript. So something like

```
let a = b = 1
```

means assign value `1` to `b`, then to `a`.

Next, if you spread all values into a single var, you're essentially doing a simple assignment with a fancy ES6 syntax. So:

```
const {...b} = a
// is same as
const b = a
```

Combining the above 3 effects, what you get is effectively a multiple assignment:

```
const {...b} = a  
const {key1, key2} = a
```

Multiple assignment can be confusing and there are linting rules to prevent such issues: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-assign

So the answer to your question is simply, No! :)

It'd need at least 2 lines to do so - one to collect props with defaults while destructuring, and another to create the next object with those props.